# Writing XML (ET.Element) to a file

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I have created an XML file using `xml.etree.ElementTree`.
The created XML basically looks like this:

```
<testsuite name="Exploatering Tests">
   <testsuite name="device"></testsuite>
   <testsuite name="management"></testsuite>
   <testsuite name="auto"></testsuite>
</testsuite>
```

It all looks good, but I want to export only the child elements into a file and for that I am using the following code:

```
# First Testsuite Level
testsuite_exploatering = ET.Element('testsuite')
testsuite_exploatering.set("name", "Exploatering Tests")
... HERE I RECURSIVELY ADD LOTS OF ELEMENT TO testsuite_exploatering
# Write XML to file
output_xml = ET.ElementTree(testsuite_exploatering)
ET.ElementTree.write(testsuite_exploatering, output_file, xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8")
```

It writes the XML element into the file correctly but how should I modify it to print only the inner elements into a file (I don't want to have the `Exploatering Tests` element written to the file). want the file to look like this:

```
   <testsuite name="device"></testsuite>
   <testsuite name="management"></testsuite>
   <testsuite name="auto"></testsuite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's a legal XML structure. If you really want to force the output into that format, maybe you can iterate over the children and write each of them like so:

```
    out_handle = open('output.xml','w')
    for child in testsuite_exploatering.getchildren():
            ET.ElementTree.write(ET.ElementTree(child), out_handle)
    out_handle.close()
```